# Wanting to generate a random maths function using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am making an ARKit game (using Swift 4) for younger children learning maths for the first time. I need to make a set of functions to generate a random simple maths question. I know how to get number generation done but trying to also generate a maths operator (+, -, %, *) is proving a challenge.

I initially thought of using an array calling each operator as a string but i need the values to be passed into the actual question so that a correct answer is known.

All it needs to do is produce a case where I can take two variables and put them into a question eg.

```
var num1 = 0
var num2 = 0


qLabel.text = "\(question)"

num1 = Int.random(in: 0.. < 10)
num2 = Int.random(in: 0.. < 10)

if (operator is a +) {

   question = "\(num1) + \(num2)"
   answer = (num1 + num2)

}
```

Can anyone help me find a way to go about this?

Comment: Where is the code that generates a random operator?

Comment: Just pick a random element from your operator array (which can be a string), then use a switch statement to inspect the value and do the actual arithmetic based on what the operator is, you can also build the string in here.

Comment: That is what I am asking, I'm not sure how to call a random operator to be used to determine what operation to run (sorry I know pseudo code above isn't great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to correspond a number with each operator:

```
let operator = Int.random(in: 0..<4)
let number1 = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
let number2 = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
switch operator {
    case 0: question = "\(number1) + \(number2)"
    case 1: question = "\(number1) - \(number2)"
    case 2: question = "\(number1) / \(number2)"
    case 3: question = "\(number1) * \(number2)"
}
```

Seeing that this is intended for little kids, you can be a little smart when you generate questions. Using a simple approach like the above might result in questions like "5 / 3" which might confuse some kids who does not know about decimal numbers. So you should probably put the logic to generate each type of question into their own `case`s.

For subtraction questions, you can check which number is larger first. Then arrange them appropriately to avoid the result being a negative number.

For division questions, you can generate two numbers, and produce a question with the product of the two numbers being divided by one of the numbers. This way you guarantee an integer solution. Something like this:

```
let number1 = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
let number2 = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
let product = number1 * number2
question = "\(product) / \(number1)"
```

Comment: So for each case can I return more than one variable? For example say it was an addition question I would want to return the question but also the answer to be usable by other functions, would I call it like

case 0: question = "\(number1) + \(number2)"
             answer = (number1 + number2)

or separate them with a comma (still learning the correct syntaxes to use when coding apologies)

Comment: @ElliotMichelmore I suggest you create a `Question` struct with a `questionText` property and  an `answer` property. Then you can return an instance of that struct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "magic bullet". For presentation to the user, you will need to choose randomly from a list of operators as strings, e.g. `["+", "-"]`, by generating a random index into the list. For actual calculation, you will have to test for which string it is and write out the corresponding calculation.

Comment: So I am trying adding the operators to an array, assigning a variable a random element of that array and using if case to determine which code to run for each operator depending on what value the variable holds. Is this correct?

Comment: Basically yes, that's right. Your terminology is a bit messy, but I think you've successfully repeated what I said.